# GitHub Api v3 failed to authorize

Tags: android, rest, authorization, github-api

Using `OkHttp` library  I try to login to GitHub with a way, described in this topic -> [Authorization for github.com on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590248/authorization-for-github-com-on-android)

```
body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("scopes", "public_repo")
            .add("note","admin script")
            .add("client_id","XXXXXXXX")
            .add("client_secret","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .build();
    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.github.com//authorizations")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXX")  //xxxx base64 login:password
            .post(body)
            .build();
```

But I've got html response with error

```
 {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due the the double /. Fix this by removing the slash.

```
.url("https://api.github.com/authorizations")
```