# Python JSON call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting to get into Python lately and was wondering if you could post some code about how to to encode a JSON string, send it as an HTTP request to a URL, and parse the response.

Here's some code I've been playing around with:

```
import os
import json

if os.name == 'nt':
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
        return
else:
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("clear", shell=True)
        return

def login_call(username, password):

choice = 0

while int(choice) not in range(1,2):
    clear_console()
    print ('')
    print ('  Json Calls - Menu')
    choice = input('''
  1. Login.

  Enter Option: ''')

print ('')

choice = int(choice)

if choice == 1:

    login_call(username, password)
```

Comment: None of the code shows even an attempt at this.

Comment: I suppose you could uses `requests` http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html to send and receive it. I'm not sure how `requests` handles sending `JSON` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an answer to do such a thing for the github api the other day. See my [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621206/741316)

In essence, the code boiled down to:

```
import urllib2
import json


data = {"text": "Hello world github/linguist#1 **cool**, and #1!"}
json_data = json.dumps(data)

req = urllib2.Request("https://api.github.com/markdown")
result = urllib2.urlopen(req, json_data)

print '\n'.join(result.readlines())
```

Comment: thanks man. All I wanted was this simple breakdown. Now, time to put it to work.

Comment: This is actually using Python 2, while the question states it is using Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The modules you'll want are `httplib` or `http.client`, depending on your version of Python, and `json`.  In JSON, the simple `loads` and `dumps` functions should encode and decode JSON easily for you.